# Job DSL - checkout repository to the workspace from DSL script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Is it possible to get my repository code from DSL script?
I need to get multiple repositories and generate jobs, I do not want to use Multiple SCM plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly you can use DSL to generate jobs that checkout your code from whatever repository.
Have a look at the excellent [DSL-API](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job-scm).
In order to test your jobs check the [Job DSL Playground](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: I do not want to create job that will checkout repository. I want to checkout repository in my Job DSL script.